# chrome extension chritter example xpath

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm not having any luck with this example.

https://sites.google.com/site/gdevelopercodelabs/chrome-extensions/codelab

I get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: xpath is not defined".

My apologies for begin such a newbie. Is xpath allowed in Manifest 2?

I really wish google would update all its code samples, tutorials and videos to work with the latest Manifest Version.